# Disable image from cross-domain content

Tags: javascript, ajax, image

Last time I have asked a way to disable javascript and I finally found the solution. However, I now want to disable also the images required by the cross-domain contents. I tried to use this command to improve: 
 `$(some_content_from_ajax).find('img').remove();` 
Yet It still did not work. How can I fix this problem?
(p.s. Ajax responded with a status of 200)

Comment: Maybe this would solve your problem: find('img')

Comment: Sorry, I typed it wrong. Yet this did not do anything to the case at all.

Comment: please edit your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(some_content_from_ajax).find('img').remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xwhcm/1/

Comment: This has no use at all. The images are still loaded.

Comment: Sorry, now I see that it doesn't work for you. Can you show us your AJAX response?